# pycurl installation issue on windows using pip and easy_install

Tags: python, pycurl

Ive been trying for a long time different commands but i always kept getting

> Please SPecify --curl....

I tried installing pycurl in a terminal, but it was not working

Comment: Keep in mind that python 2 is officially end of life. Please update to python 3

Answer (score 0):

Pycurl installers can directly be downloaded from from https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/ for your respective Python version

Answer (score 0):

What's the python version you are using? PycURL is only supported for specific versions.
**Python 2.7 or 3.4 through 3.6.**

Other Python versions won't be able to install PycURL via pip or easy_install , you'll have to manually compile it.